# setFocus in useEffect cause errors in tests

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, karma-runner, enzyme

I have written several tests for my React Component and they all work when I exclude the following code:

```
useEffect(() => {
    if (lastClickedElement) {
        const findElement = document.getElementById(lastClickedElement);
        findElement.focus();
    } else {
        const findFirstLink = document.querySelectorAll("a");
        findFirstLink[0].focus();
    }
```

However when I do include it I receive error: "Cannot read property 'focus' of undefined".
Can anyone explain why my tests would work without it and then cause this error when its included?

I have tried to have an if statement that returns nothing if findFirstLink equals "null" but then I receive this error "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'focus' of null thrown".

Code looks something like this:

```
{data.items.map((item, i) => {
      return (
           <div>
                <a href={item.id}>{item.label}</a>
           </div>
             )
         }
)}
```

Comment: Maybe semi related question, why use `document.getElementById` instead of passing a `ref` to the relevant element and use `ref.current.focus()`?

Answer (score 0):

It's because jest doesn't run in a headless browser, so there is no `document` so to speak.

best solution for a quick fix would be to mock your getElementByID and querySelectorAll to return an array with an object that has `focus: jest.fn()`